# text inside button cannot move

Tags: html, css

I have a video on the same line with a button 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ts5bQ.png

The button is too low, so I typed `style="line-height:60px;text-align:center;"`to move it up 
 but the text inside the button didn't move

```
<span style="padding-right:60px;">
        <input id="text" type="button" value="Text" onClick= "a()" class="defaut_button" style="line-height:60px;text-align:center;">
    </span>
    <span>
        <video controls="controls" tabindex="0" width="800">
            <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" width="80%" height="20%">
        </video>
    </span>
```

Comment: Provide complete CSS for this part, this is not enough to recreate problem...

Comment: The button is too low? Seems like you need margin / padding?